# How to access original base class method if it has been overridden in child class?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am replacing some javascript's built in classes by extending them and methods by overriding original ones, with my own versions. However, I sometimes in my overridden methods want to access original ones. However, javascript allows me that only some times, where other times it does not. This is very unpredictable behavior, and I do not know what it is going on. It appears that the same method with the same parameters has different results each time it is called.

Here is example of one javascript's built in class and method i modified and got this strange behavior:

```js
//Inherit everything from original String class in STRING class.
class STRING extends String
{
    //Redefine behavior of original replace method.
    replace()
    {
        //Get original javascript's replace method definition from prototype
        //of this class's prototype (base class) and attach it to this
        //object's instance, and then run it and pass anything it returns
        //back to the caller.
        return this.__proto__.__proto__.replace.call(this);
    }
}
//Replace original javascript's replace method with custom replace method
//everywhere, including in string primitives.
String.prototype.replace = STRING.prototype.replace;
//Replace whole original javascript's String class with custom STRING class.
String = STRING;
//Create custom string primitive.
let a = "hello stacky";
//Call custom replace method in custom string primitive.
a.replace();
```

What this code essentially does is that it just does whatever default javascript's `String` class and `replace` method in `String` class would do, only by passing it through my custom class and method. (like a proxy).

Please ignore that some things are missing and that this code is pointless because it does nothing. I only simplified it to be able to show you the problem. So, I know that there should be two parameters of the `replace` method, but let us ignore this for now. It will work even without parameters (`replace` method works the same as `toString` method when no parameters are given).

After defining `STRING` class as extension of `String` class, I copy `replace` method to `String` prototype, because otherwise, only `STRING` and `String` objects would have that method, but not `string` primitives.

Then I create test primitive, and call my custom `replace` method on it.

This should output `hello stacky` since if you call `replace` method on `STRING` without parameters it will be the same as calling `toString` method.

Inside `replace` method following statements should be true, and they sometimes are, and sometimes are not:

1. First, `this` is called, which returns `STRING` object.
2. After that, first `__proto__` accessor is called. This should return prototype of that `STRING` object, and that is my custom `STRING` class.
3. Next, second `__proto__` accessor is called. This should return prototype of the prototype of this object. So, since prototype of `STRING` object is `STRING` class, second `__proto__` should return prototype of the `STRING` class. And that should be original javascript's `String` class.
4. Next, `replace` method is called. Since second `__proto__` should return `String` class, this `replace` method should be original javascript's `replace` method definition.
5. And finally `call` method is called over `replace` method, and context of `this` object is provided to that method. This should attach original javascript's `replace` method to this string, execute it, and return its result into custom `replace` method in `STRING` class.
   Then custom `replace` method returns whatever it got from the called method back to the caller. So, output should be equal to hello stacky.

However, this does not work every time. When it does not work following is true:

1. `this` refers to current `STRING` object.
2. `this.__proto__` also refers to current `STRING` object.
3. `this.__proto__.__proto__` somehow as well refers to current `STRING` object.
4. `this.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__` referes to `Object`.

I have also tried accessing `replace` from `String` class using `super` instead of `this.__proto__.__proto__`, but it still does not access the right method.

When it does not work, this code returns `typeError: this.__proto__.__proto__.replace is undefined:.`.

I know I am probably missing something here, but, do not know what. Or MongoDB is not working properly.

I really do not know what happened.

I get it, in my code I have line: `String=STRING` which is tricky, since `STRING` is subclass of `String`, and this might cause `String` class to get completely wiped out and replaced with `STRING` class which is its own parent.
And according to `this.__proto__.__proto__` `STRING` class is its own parent, since, prototype of `STRING` class is another `STRING` class, and prototype of that `STRING` class is `Object` class, not `String` class.

In this example here, I removed 99% of the code, but I kept parts important for this problem. This code really does produce the same error as my original code.

What is probably important for you to know is how I test this code.
For testing I used mongodb shell.

Also, it is important to mention that I am using mongodb version 4.1.6, which is beta, and thus unstable version of mongo. It might be the source of this strange behavior.

So, my question to you is: Why this code worked yesterday, but it does not work anymore today?
And if you can not answer that, then, can you tell me what should I do to accomplish this task correctly?

Task is:
Define child class of `String` class which has to override `replace` method, and make sure every instance of string, no matter weather created by using `STRING` constructor, `String` constructor or `""` has the same, custom behavior when `replace` method is called.

Comment: You shouldn't try to do this, its an anti pattern and possibly evil. What are you actually trying to accomplish by doing this? Some of these primitive types are special native objects and probably won't have the same semantics as the objects and classes you define yourself. Its probably unspecified behavior and may vary from browser to browser.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you're trying to accomplish here — and for the record this seems like A Bad Idea™ — but if you must, have you considered using [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)?

```js
class Wookie extends String {
  replace(...args) {
    return super.replace.apply(this, args);
  }
}

const wookie = new Wookie("chewbacca");
console.log(wookie.replace('c', 'b'));
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for suggestion. Yes, this works fine in case I wanted to just override ```replace``` method in child class and call super method from there. But that is easy, I would not ask something like that. There are already answered questions about overriding method. Your code will only call overridden ```replace``` method in case you create string with ```new Wookie``` constructor. But I am trying to accomplish something more advanced here.

Comment: I wish to inject this overridden method from ```STRING``` (or in your case ```Wookie```) class into both ```String``` class and ```string``` primitives. So I want that custom ```replace``` method is executed in all of these cases: ```new STRING()``` ```new String()``` and ```""```. If we define ```replace``` method as: ```return super.replace.call(this,"a","o");``` then I want all of the following to be true: ```new STRING("hay").replace()``` should return ```hoy```. ```new String("hay").replace()``` should return ```hoy```. ```"hay".replace()``` should return ```hoy```.

Comment: I hope you understand what I am trying to do now. So I want the same method to be called no matter if it is called from ```STRING``` (or in your case ```Wookie```) object, ```String``` object or string primitive. (```""```).